# Can syntax highlighting be made available?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

While I wouldn't expect `vimscript` to be immediately available for highlighting, I think other languages aren't available either. I just tried to add it to [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/280/205) using both `<!-- language: bash -->` and `<!-- language: lang-sh -->` to no effect in the edit preview (so I didn't submit the suggestion).

Comment: I just did notice now that is no support for Vim on Google Prettify :|

Comment: How well would the naïve syntax highlighting work with Vimscript? Enabling syntax highlighting might be harmful, if Vimscript doesn't look good.

Comment: @200_success You can force disable syntax highlighting. And I don't know how the default is determined, but if the default can be set to no highlighting, that would be good too.

Comment: I would love to help out with this feature. I think it is important, especially since many questions will be filed under `.vimrc` where highlighting would be helpful. From my experience, highlighting may not appear until you post and scroll through the page... Or unless the correct language is a tag.

Comment: @muru cant you enable this as a moderator?

Comment: @StevenPenny as far as I know, nope. It has to be enabled by SE devs.

Comment: @StevenPenny checked, muru's right. There are no mod options to do this, I think because it's a feature disabled by default.

Comment: Do we have to wait the end of the beta phase to get this feature enabled? It can help discerning comments or keywords and comes in useful with shell scripts for example. [SE uses the tags on the question to infer the language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/368425).

Comment: @LEI this is status-completed; syntax highlighting has been enabled months ago.

Comment: @muru Oh right. I understand that to enable a new language on SE it has to be merged upstream, or does it? [This gist](https://gist.github.com/hail2u/1566304) if working properly could add support for `vimscript` here. For the record there is no feature or pull request [on GitHub](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/search?q=vimscript), at the moment.

Comment: @LEI you should check out the linked posts. See https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1341/205